# Flutter image_picker pre-select images

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I'm using the flutter image_picker plugin. I can use

```
 final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
 final List<XFile> images = await picker.pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 60);
```

After a user has picked multiple images for their post and exit out, they can always go back and select more images - in which case I want the images already selected to be "pre-selected". The API has no way to do this I think, so I'm wondering if there is a similar/reliable plugin that can do this and is well supported.

I've googled and found multiple plugins for image picking - and none of them seem to support this feature. I'm tempted to try and roll my own but would prefer to find a plugin if one exists. Any recommendations I could try?